# how to stop header from scrolling at some point and make it fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a header, in which i put my `h1` and `h2` headings at top. The problem is that header scrolls along the scroll bar which is of course normal but i want to fixed it at some point when all the headings on header scroll away. At this point I want header to stop and stays fixed.

I already tried fixed position but of course it fixed heading as well which exactly I don't want.

I also tried this JavaScript but no luck.

### JavaScript

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var _height = 120 - (120 * $(this).scrollTop() / $('body').height());

    if (_height >= 80) {
        $('.header_container').height(_height);
    }
});
```

and here qre my HTML and CSS codes respectively.

### HTML

```
<div class="header_container" id="header_container">
    <div id="header_titles">
        <h1 class="homepage-heading">Browse</h1>
        <h2 class="homepage-heading-subtle">GENRES & MOODS</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#header_container {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#header_titles {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let me see if I get this...you want your header to be scrolled normally with the page until a certain point where it becomes fixed?

**EDIT**

Ok, well, you could determine the element on the page that you want the position to be triggered at. Like, the  top of a certain paragraph, and use that position in your condition.

```
var condition = $(element).offset().top;
if($(window).scrollTop > condition) { //add a fixedClassName } else { remove the fixedClassName }
```

and have header.fixedClassName have those proprieties ( with position fix, top 0 and width: 100% to your header etc). Be sure to add and remove a class on the body that gives it padding-top with the height of your displaced header.

Used some similar effect here http://goodmen.se/ after a point the logo shows up in the header, then there's a background change. You do something similar with your position.

**EDIT 2**

Here's an example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Corsico/vpskd8hd/

Comment: I do want to get his question right, thanks. Can't comment because I don't have enough reputation to comment apparently.

Comment: @VladPintea - I understand that but at SO, it shouldn't make it to an answer to maintain the quality. There are other great ways of earning reputation before you can comment. :)

Comment: @arcade edited the answer to my new understanding of the question. Hope it helps. If more details are needed be sure to let me know.

Comment: plz can u reedit your answer with full code example because i tried it my self but still nothing achieved.

Comment: @arcade I will get back to you in a couple minutes with a jsfiddle

Comment: @arcade check out the fiddle, see if it fits your needs. If you need help adapting it to your case let me know.

Comment: plz link to the jsfiddle!

Comment: @arcade: I did, it's in the answer

Comment: ok sorry for that! thanks by the way. i will check then tell u.

Comment: thanks for your kind help but its only works on jsfiddle not on my scenario moreover i want header to stopped as soon as two headings on it passed away. in your fiddle its first whole header scrolled then after some delay it sticks with headings as well which is exactly i don't want. plz check this effect on this link (https://youtu.be/yn4ZncKa8SI) where i inspired.

Comment: that's easily doable adapting the code I've shown to your case. If you can provide a link, or the actual markup, I can modify the fiddle precisely to do what you want. In the video demo, the trigger is when the headings are out of view, then the header sticks. You need to change the condition accordingly and the outcome inside the if.

Comment: can i give u my whole site so u better see and figure it out?

Comment: now i moved my nested div outside of it and it some how works but not on homepage! by the way how i give to you my site?

Comment: @arcade is it live or on localhost? If it's local you could try putting it as a fiddle and sharing that. I dunno.

Comment: on localhost but i can't put all this on fiddle because it has lots of pages uploded it on somwhere else so you have to download it and then test it.

Comment: by the way can i have your skype, facebook other contact for better communication?

Answer (score 1):

So you want a sticky header?

In your javascript create a code:

```
var $header_container = $('#header_container');
var header_height = $header_container.outerHeight(true);

if($(window).scrollTop() < header_height){
    $header_container.removeClass('sticky');
} else{
    $header_container.addClass('sticky');
}

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()< header_height){
        $header_container.removeClass('sticky');
    } else{
        $header_container.addClass('sticky');
    }
});
```

This will add a `sticky` class to your header, and then you can set the header to be fixed:

```
.sticky{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

This should do it. When you scroll pass the height of the header, you'll get the 'sticky' class, if not, you'll remove the sticky class...

Comment: i tried this but no luck! please help me to figure this out.

Comment: Remove all the position css styles from your `#header_container` - `  top: 0;left: 0;right: 0;` - if the header is static those could interfere later on when you add sticky class. The above code should add class when you scroll...